# how update database fields in orm+python when tables column is changed?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, database-migration

I use Sqlalchemy orm,python, python migrate for my project that is a project about Accounting.
my issue is:
for example in version 1 the fields of a tables has a 4 colomun. I release project and a person use this for her work. he input data to table.
I work in project and release version 2 of project so that the has 5 fields.
how to update the project to last version so that data in older table import to new table.
merci.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [alembic](http://alembic.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). It provides you with the ability to do table migrations on software updates. Read the documentation on how to integrate it in your project.